# Using hooks -- simple please

Tags: extension, activities, hooks

I am excited to be working with civicrm, but I am quite frustrated at this point and so I hope someone can help me.

I can see how valuable hooks are, and it seems like they are actually very basic to implement, but I need a small amount of pre-knowledge to use them.  I have read every link I could find about hooks to change forms and yet I find myself lost.

I did find one example that fit my needs exactly, and would be a great learning experience ... but the description leaves out a lot of necessary information for someone as new as me.

Can someone walk me though implementing this? It comes from [How can I set “Assigned To” for an Activity to default](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/how-can-i-set-assigned-to-for-an-activity-to-default-to-the-logged-in-user-nam)

The extension mentioned in the comment above is:

`function myextension_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Activity_Form_Activity' && $form->action == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
    $form->setDefaults(array('assignee_contact_id' => $form->_currentUserId));
  }
}`

- How do I find the 'create activity' form this relates to?

> I got that answer myself -- **CRM** _ **Activity** _ **Form** _ **Activity**
>   means the php file is in
>
> /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/**CRM**/**Activity**/**Form**
>   and then **activity.php**

- Do I copy the form to my /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm_extensions directory?
- Do I put that function inside the form I copied?
- Do I create that as a file?
- If a file, what do I name it?
- Where do I put the extension once I create it?

You are all very helpful and I appreciate it. Thank you in advance for any help you can give me on this problem I face.

Just a note about searching for answers: About a month or two ago I found a web page that explained some of this to me but for the life of me I fail to find that page today. I did find a lot of links that looked like they could help but a whole mess of them led to (Page Not Found) on http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/. Seems a lot of pages were deleted or renamed.

Thanks again.

Comment: Note that the example code from that answer has just been updated to fix an error. You might want to change your hook code as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a hook, you can:

- Write a CiviCRM extension.  This is the preferred method.
- Write a Drupal module.
- Write a Joomla or Wordpress plugin.

The easiest way to write a CiviCRM extension is to install [civix](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) and run `civix generate:module org.myorg.myextension`.  Then you can edit myextension.php and paste in that code.

However, as that page says - this presumes that you have a basic knowledge of PHP, Unix, and object-oriented programming.  If that's not a skill you're going to learn today, and you want to cheat a little - take an existing extension and hack it!  Download an existing function, preferably one that does very little, and modify it to your needs.  I just uploaded an extension to Github that fits this need exactly [here](https://github.com/PalanteJon/org.cpehn.module.contributionpagecustomizations).

Comment: Thank you. Do I put that in  /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm_extensions and then inside a folder, in your case, namedcontributionpagecustomizations?

Comment: Thank you. I got that to work, renaming your folder, php file names and I replaced your 'contributionpagecustomizations' with my 'formcustomization'  in the php files. Got it to install in 'Manage Extension' but --- if ($formName == 'CRM_Activity_Form_Activity' && $form->getaction() == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {$form->setDefaults(array('assignee_contact_id' => $form->_currentUserId)); --- did not set the default assignee to current user. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it. That did work, just had to refresh the page! Thank you, new horizons await me!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is also a pretty basic example here: https://github.com/CiviCooP/no.maf.oppgavexml
This extension creates 2 files, introduces a page and a form. Might be able to give you some more understanding. But the real recommendation would be to take part in a CiviCRM developer training or CiviCRM sprint? Depending on where you are in the world you might be interested in a developer training in London that is coming up?